# Show shipping class in admin product list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin

I'm looking for a way to show the Shipping Class of a product in the product admin overview to be able to quickly check if the right shipping class was selected for a product.

Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new column to the product admin overview that displays the shipping class of each product. Here's how you can do it:

1. Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file or a custom plugin:

   ```
    // Add new 'Shipping Class' column to the product admin overview
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'show_product_shipping_class_column' );
    function show_product_shipping_class_column( $columns ) {
        $columns['shipping_class'] = __( 'Shipping Class', 'woocommerce' );
        return $columns;
    }

    // Populate 'Shipping Class' column with the product's shipping class
    add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'populate_product_shipping_class_column', 10, 2 );
    function populate_product_shipping_class_column( $column, $postid ) {
        if ( $column == 'shipping_class' ) {
            $_product = wc_get_product( $postid );
            $shipping_class = $_product->get_shipping_class();

            if ( ! empty( $shipping_class ) ) {
                echo $shipping_class;
            } else {
                echo '<span class="na">–</span>';
            }
        }
    }

    // Make 'Shipping Class' column sortable
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'sortable_product_shipping_class_column' );
    function sortable_product_shipping_class_column( $columns ) {
        $columns['shipping_class'] = 'shipping_class';
        return $columns;
    }
   ```

This code does three things:

- It adds a new 'Shipping Class' column to the product admin overview.
- It populates this column with the shipping class of each product.
- It makes the 'Shipping Class' column sortable.

Now, when you go to the product admin overview, you should see a new 'Shipping Class' column that displays the shipping class of each product. You can click on the column header to sort the products by their shipping class.